# How to print new sequence in main function?

Tags: c

I have a program that will form a new sequence (sequence + piece) of numbers based on a couple conditions.

I need to print the new sequence formed in the function called `Concat` in the main function but also need the `Concat` to return 1 so it is known in the main function that the sequence to be printed is valid.

here is my code:

```
#define BUFFER 50

int Concat(char sequence[], char piece[]){
    int sequenceValid = 1;
    int sizeSequence = strlen(sequence);
    if(sequence[sizeSequence-1] == piece[0]){
        sequence = strcat(sequence,piece);
    } else if(sequence[0] == piece[1]){
        sequence = strcat(piece,sequence);
    } else {
        sequenceValid = 0;
    }
    return sequenceValid;
}

int main()
{
 char piece[BUFFER], sequence[BUFFER];
 scanf("%s", sequence);
 scanf("%s", piece);

 if (Concat(sequence, piece)){
    printf("%s", sequence); // at this stage the new sequence formed above by the method `strcat` should be printed ( sequence + piece) not just the sequence, however only the sequence is printed. 
 }
 else{
    printf("piece %s cannot be added %s.",piece, sequence);
 }
}
```

As per my note above, if the `Concat` function returns true(1) it is printing only the sequence as given by the user and not the sequence + piece which is what I want.

**Test example:**
Input:

166335
21

Desired output: 21166335

Current output (errored): 166335

How to print the new sequence in the main function?

Comment: The main caller does not know whether you added `piece` to `sequence`, or `sequence` to `piece`. Setting `sequence` in the function does nothing - it just overwrites the local copy of the pointer.

Comment: As @WeatherVane posted, changing `sequence = strcat(piece,sequence);` to `strcat(piece,sequence);strcpy(sequence, piece);` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three things you need to remember when it comes to function arguments in C:

1. The first is that an argument like `char sequence[]` is really treated as `char *sequence`, that is it's a pointer.
2. The second thing is that all arguments are really local variables to the functions, and their life-time ends when the function ends.
3. The third thing is that all arguments are passed *by value*, which means the value at the site of the call is copied into the functions local argument variable.

All put together, all assignments you make to `sequence` will be lost once the function returns.

Simple solution: Return `sequence` at the end (or a null pointer on invalid sequence).

Comment: Can't we accept pointer-to-pointer of `sequence` in the function `Concat` (using reference operator on `sequence` when calling function `Concat`), and then using de-referencing operator on `sequence` in the function (like using `*sequence` instead of `sequence`)?

Comment: @user1234 Yes that work, but then you need an extra variable in the `main` function (it won't be possible to use `&sequence` in the call to the function). Though you still need an extra variable for the returned pointer anyway, so it's mostly a matter of personal preference.